# Python list manipulation: Given a list of ranges number, return the list of combined ranges

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting

I was given this problem during a phone interview:

> Suppose there is a list of ranges. For example, [[1-6],[10-19],[5-8]]. 
>   Write a function that returns the list of combined ranges
>   such that input [[1-6],[10-19],[5-8]] to the function returns
>   [[1,8],[10,19]] (only the start and end number). Note, the input list 
>   may contain arbitrary number of
>   ranges.

My solution to this problem is:

1. Combine all range list into one list:
   [[1-6],[10-19],[5-8]] -> [1-6,10-19,5-8]
2. Perform sorting on the list:
   list = Sorted(list) -> [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,7,8,10...]
3. Use list = set(list) to get rid of the redundant numbers
4. Iterate through the list and find the range

I know this solution is definitely what they are looking for (that's why I failed the interview terribly) as the time complexity is O(nlogn) (sorting), n is the number of distinct numbers in the range.

Can you python expert gives a O(n) solution, n as the number of ranges in the original list?

Comment: can there be empty ranges?

Comment: Did you mean to say it's definitely **not** what they are looking for?

Comment: What is the max value of the numbers in the range for example if a range is [x,y] what is the max value of x and y? If it is less you can do it in O(max_val(x))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the solution mentioned in the question is not O(nlgn), where n is the number of segments. This is O(Xlg(X))where, `X = length of the segment*num of segments`, which is terribly slow.
An O(NlgN) solution exists where N is the number of segments.

1. Sort the segments by their starting point.
2. Sweep across the sorted list and check if the current segment overlaps with the previous one. If yes, then extend the previous segment if required.

Sample code:

```
inp = [[1,6], [10,19], [5,8]]

inp = sorted(inp)
segments = []

for i in inp:
    if segments:
        if segments[-1][1] >= i[0]:
            segments[-1][1] = max(segments[-1][1], i[1])
            continue
    segments.append(i)

print segments # [[1, 8], [10, 19]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html) to create a heap from the ranges. Then pop range from a heap and if it overlaps with the top of the heap replace the top with merged range. If there's no overlap or there's no more ranges append it to result:

```
import heapq

def merge(ranges):
    heapq.heapify(ranges)
    res = []

    while ranges:
        start, end = heapq.heappop(ranges)
        if ranges and ranges[0][0] <= end:
            heapq.heapreplace(ranges, [start, max(end, ranges[0][1])])
        else:
            res.append((start, end))

    return res

ranges = [[1,6],[10,19],[5,8]]
print(merge(ranges))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 8), (10, 19)]
```

Above has **O(n log n)** time complexity where **n** is the number of ranges.

Answer (score 1):

In case range is [x,y] and max_x,y is less probably within a few millions you can do this

The idea is that I use the technique of hashing to put them in sorted order taking advantage of lower max_y.

We then iterate and keep the current 'good' range is variables mn and mx.

When a new range comes if it is entirely outside the 'good' range, we append the good range and make the new range as the good range. Otherwise we change the good range accordingly.

```
max_y = 1000000
range_sort = [None]*max_y

ranges =  [[1,6],[10,19],[5,8]]
for r in ranges:
    if range_sort[r[0]] is not None and range_sort[r[0]]>=r[1]:
         continue   ## handling the case [1,5] [1,8]
    range_sort[r[0]] = r[1]   # in the list lower value is stored as index, higher as value

mx = -1
mn = 1000000000
ans = []
for x,y in enumerate(range_sort): # The values are correct as explained in comment above
    if y is None:
        continue   #To remove the null values

    if x<mn:
        mn = x    # This will change the lower value of current range

    if x>mx and mx>0: # If lower val x higher than current upper mx
        ans.append([mn,mx])  # append current lower (mn) and upper(mx)
        mn = x   
        mx = y   # change the current upper and lower to the new one 

    if y>mx:
        mx = y   # This will change upper value of current range

ans.append([mn,mx]) # This has to be outside as last range won't get appended

print ans
```

Output: [[1,8],[10,19]]

Time complexity **O(MAX_y)**